# Getting UnsuportedClassVersionError when trying to load servlet on tomcat running on debian

Tags: java, tomcat, debian

I'm developing and testing my project on a windows machine with tomcat 7.0 and compiling in compliance with JDK 1.7. This works fine. Trouble starts when I try to deploy the .war file on a Debian machine, again with tomcat 7.0.

I'm getting the following error when I try to access the website:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/smartapes/tingy/web/servlets/MainServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.smartapes.tingy.web.servlets.MainServlet)
```

Running `java -version` prints

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-2~deb7u1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Check in logs if tomcat really  is running with java 7, seems that is running with a different version.

Comment: Apparently tomcat is launched with `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java` but as I understand, that would be version 1.7, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was indeed that tomcat, instead of being started with the openjdk-7-jre, it was started with the also installed default-jre. Once I removed that with `apt-get remove default-jre-headless` and restarted the tomcat service, the website worked.